# How to implement feature like hike Sticky in Android?

Tags: android

I want to implement a feature similar to Sticky option in [Hike](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsb.hike&hl=en) android app. 
Its something related to Accessibility services in Android, but I'm not able to understand how to implement it.

Basically what this feature does is that it suggests stickers based on what the user is typing in other apps like whatsapp or facebook.

Please can anyone provide a tutorial or code through which this feature is implemented.